# Resolve into partial fractions $(x^2 + 3x - 5)/[(2x - 7)(x^2 + 3)^2]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, partial-fractions

> Resolve into partial fractions $\frac{x^2 + 3x - 5}{(2x - 7)(x^2 + 3)^3}$

The question has to do with the denominator being one linear and a repeated quadratic factor. Although, I am familiar with the aspect of resolving fractions in their partial forms as regards the denominator being repeated linear factors; but with the repeated quadratic, the problem lies before me as a cumbersome task. I really need help in tackling such a problem like this. Thanks!

Comment: That does look like it’s going to be tedious. After clearing denominators, but before expanding everything, you can make computing some of the coefficients a bit simpler by setting $x=7/2$ and $x=\pm i\sqrt3$.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Ansatz":

$\frac{(x^2 + 3x - 5)}{(2x - 7)(x^2 + 3)^3}= \frac{A}{2x-7}+\frac{Bx+C}{x^2+3}+\frac{Dx+E}{(x^2+3)^2}+\frac{Fx+G}{(x^2+3)^3}.$